# How do I immediately put a drive to sleep (without changing its power setting configuration)?

Tags: command-line, hard-disk, power-management

Within GNOME's "Disks" utility there is the option to immediately put a drive into sleep / standby, which spins down the platters.  I would like to do this on my servers before pulling hot-swap drives out for offsite backup rotation--but so far I haven't found the needed command (there are a lot of references for changing the drive settings using `hdparm`, but nothing to do a one-time immediate sleep).

What command would immediately put a drive to sleep, without altering it's persistent power configuration settings?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`hdparm -Y /dev/sdx` should do that.

Comment: `-Y Force  an  IDE drive to immediately enter the lowest power consumption sleep mode` -- perfect!  Thanks!